# Windows上でApacheをビルドしたい

Tags: visual-studio, apache

**Windows上でApacheを構築したい**

下記のサイトを参考に「VisualStudio2013」を用いて、ソースコードから、
Windows上でApacheを構築したいと考えています。

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1247932/How-to-Build-Apache-on-Windows

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

上記サイトの「Apr Build」で問題が発生しています。
apr、apr-iconv、apr-utilをビルドするため、
Visual Studioでaprutil.dswを起動し、プロジェクトをアップグレードする際のエラーです。

Visual Studioの移行レポートに以下のエラーが記述されていました。

---

srclib\apr-util\libaprutil.dsp: プロジェクトを変換できません。 このプロジェクトが有効な Visual C++ 6.0 プロジェクトであることを確認してください。

srclib\apr-util\libaprutil.dsp: プロジェクトはアップグレードに失敗しました。

srclib\apr-util\libaprutil.dsp: プロジェクト ファイル 'C:\httpd\srclib\apr-util\libaprutil.dsp' を変換しています。

---

Visual C++ 6.0 のプログラムが必要かと思っているのですが、
知見がある方がいらっしゃいましたら、解決方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか。

**試したこと**
下記の環境でビルドを試しましたが同じエラーで、できませんでした。
・VisualStudio2013
・VisualStudio2015
・VisualStudio2017

**補足情報**
以下のツールのバージョンを使用しています。
・Apache 2.4.33
・Apr 1.6.5 （参考サイトでは1.6.3でしたが、見つからなかったので1.6.5を使用しています）
・Apr-util 1.6.1
・Apr-iconv 1.2.2
・Expat 2.2.5
・Pcre 8.42
・VisualStudio2013
・Windows10

Windows上でApacheの構成ができればいいので、上記方法以外で構築経験がある方がいれば、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

公式の手順[Compiling Apache for Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/win_compiling.html)は参照されていますでしょうか？ perlやawkが必要と言及されていますが。